# Non-resizing slider in XCode first tutorial

Tags: xcode, cocoa, slider, xcode4.5, autolayout

I've just finished the [Your First App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/Introduction.html) tutorial for OS X. Except I notice that in the final section on "Polish", the effect of resizing the window is not at all like the expected screenshot.[image: Scrunched window]

That shot has a text field at the top, a button at the bottom, and a vertical slider in between. My slider has an undeleteable(?) constraint of a fixed height, the height I made it when I first dropped it on the form. So when I shrink the window, I get truncation

[image: truncated window]

As I said, I can't delete or switch to "Less than or equals" the constraint on the vertical slider. What do I do here to get intelligent auto-layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Apple seems to be a little slow in updating their Tutorials. If you are deploying to [Mountain] Lion, the resizing works with the constraints differently than implied in the Tutorial. I got the desired effect by

1. Creating a constraint between the Push Button and the bottom of the view. (There was already such a constraint for the top; this seems to have to do a little with where you hovered as you dragged it onto the form originally. If not, I would have created it.)
2. Creating a constraint between the Push Button and the Slider. Again, there already was a constraint like this at the top of the form.
3. **Setting the priority of the Height constraint for the slider to a number much lower than the 1000 value for the other constraints.** Modifying the value doesn’t work, but modifying priority does.

The observed behavior now matches expectations. Hope this helps someone else.